# Программно сделать скрин сайта

Tags: php, java, веб-программирование

Доброго времени суток! Как можно программно сделать скрин сайта? Т.е. пользователь вводит `url` и получает скрин этого сайта.

Comment: Справа есть блок **Связанные вопросы**, там есть **Скрин сайта**.  
Там Вы дали свой ответ.  
Помимо Вашего ответа там есть ссылка на сайт, позволяющий делать скрины.  
Помимо этого можно скачать сорцы этого проекта с гита (проект сделан на питоне) и ими делать скрины.  
Можно не заморачиваться с исходниками и делать запросы на скриншот к этому сайту и вытягивать результат с него.

Comment: я хочу сам понять, как это делается и надеюсь кто-то подскажет мне с чего начать

Comment: и желательно, как это реализовать на php или на java

Answer (score 1):

Как на пхп - уже привели ссылку.

На джаве - с помощью [htmlunit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/)